Prove that the homomorphism induced by a retraction is an epimorphism
If $r:X\rightarrow A$ is a retraction and $a_0\in A$, then $r_*:\Pi_1(X,a_0)\rightarrow\Pi_1(A,a_0)$ is an epimorphism.
Proof: By definition, $r_*$ is a homomorphism. We now show that $r_*$ is surjective. Suppose $[h]\in\Pi_1(A,a_0)$. Let $h\in[h]$. Then clearly all points of $h$ are in $A$, and so they are also in $X$.
Hence $[h]\in\Pi_1(X,a_0)$. Therefore $r_*([h])=[r\circ h]=[h]$ and $r_*$ is an epimorphism.
I'm just not sure whether my reasoning about $[h]$ at the end is valid.

Your proof is mostly okay, but it has a notational ambiguity: the symbol $[h]$ appears to have two separate meanings depending on whether you regard it as an element of $\pi_1(A,a_0)$ or as an element of $\pi_1(X,a_0)$.
You should therefore invent two separate notations, for example $[h]_A$ and $[h]_X$, and use those to rewrite your proof. The notation $[h]_A$ refers to the set of path homotopy classes in $A$ of closed paths in $A$ based at $a_0$; and similarly for $[h]_X$ but replace "in $A$" with "in $X$".

The idea of your proof is correct, but it should be properly elaborated. Here are some suggestions.

"Suppose $[h]\in\Pi_1(A,a_0)$. Let $h\in[h]$."
The part "let $h\in[h]$" is superfluous. Writing $[h]\in\Pi_1(A,a_0)$ means that you take an element of $\Pi_1(A,a_0)$ which is represented by $h$.

"Then clearly all points of $h$ are in $A$."
$h$ is a map, thus the "all points of $h$" part does not make sense. What you really mean is this: If $i : A \to X$ denotes inclusion, then $i \circ h$ is a map with codomain $X$, i.e. $[i \circ h] \in \Pi_1(X,a_0)$. Clearly $r_*([i \circ h]) = [r \circ i \circ h]  = [h]$.


Let us summarize these arguments. We know that $r \circ i = id$, thus $r_* \circ i_* = (r \circ i)_* = id_* = id$. Therefore, given $\alpha \in \Pi_1(A,a_0)$, we get $\beta := i_*(\alpha) \in \Pi_1(X,a_0)$ and $r_*(\beta) = \alpha$.
